# No puedo insertar codigo r dentro de un texto en R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown

Estoy intentando insertar codigo r en un texto en R Markdown pero no lo consigo.

El código que tengo en el chunk es el siguiente:

```
tot_graf<-round(nrow(Dur_graf),0)
Part_0.02<-round(nrow((Dur_graf[Dur_graf[,5]<=0.02,]))/tot_graf,3)*100
```

y el texto es:

Área 1: El `r Part_0.02`% de los activos de la Cartera se encuentra en esta área.

La idea es que me inserte el valor que surge de `Part_0.02` pero me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pueden ayudar, estaría muy agradecido

Comment: Este problema se suele dar cuando aparecen caracteres multibytes cuando no se los está esperando, hay varias causas. Lamentablemente para poder responder la pregunta sería necesario, contar con el Script completo y el set de datos completo.

Comment: Al parecer es un problema que surge a la hora de cargar tu base de datos. Tienes que compartir el código completo.